# QEMU loader device - load bare metal binary in same address space

Tags: arm, qemu, xilinx, firmware, bare-metal

For reference, I'm running bare-metal QEMU-6.1.0 on aarch64 using the [Xilinx fork](https://github.com/Xilinx/qemu).

I am loading a monolithic bare-metal binary into `qemu-system-aarch64` using the [generic loader device](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/generic-loader.html) and am writing some peripheral drivers for it. The problem is that the binary is loaded in a separate address space from the one where custom devices are loaded.

Is there any way that I can specify the address space into which the device loader will load a bare-metal binary?

The method I used for loading the binary can be found in the *Running a bare-metal application on Zynq Ultrascale+ MPSoC r5* section of the [QEMU Xilinx docs](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/821854273/Running+Bare+Metal+Applications+on+QEMU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using the exported `address_space_memory` reference in `cpu_address_space_init` instead of the `AddressSpace` reference that was being assigned by default.

```c
void cpu_address_space_init(CPUState *cpu, int asidx,
                            const char *prefix, MemoryRegion *mr)
{

    AddressSpace *as = &address_space_memory;
    //...
}
```